# PHP ldap_bind() - invalid credentials

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

I have a problem in using `ldap_bind()` method.

This is how I use it:

```
$boolIsAuth = ldap_bind($link_identifier, $bind_rdn, $bind_password);
```

And now the problem. If I provide a valid `$bind_rdn` and a valid `$bind_password`, the authentication will be made and everything will work perfectly. But, when I provide a valid `$bind_rdn` and a `$bind_password` different from the one from LDAP server the authentication process stops by throwing the following warning:

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
```

I was wondering how can I skip this error? I already tried to place an `@` in front of the function but I don't know why it's not working. It should have ignore the warning but... I don't know why it doesn't work.

I would like to treat this as an Exception but I can't do that. How can I skip it?

Comment: Skip it? Why would you want to?

Comment: I use this to authenticate a user against LDAP. If the password is not the one from the server, the script execution stops even though it should return `false`.

Comment: what does $bookIsAuth contain? true or false? The @ in front of the ldap_bind should suppress the error message at least when you are using the default error handler

Comment: I am not using the default error handler and I think that the variable state is not set because the execution stops with the warning. I read something about the custom error handler and that this may cause @ not to work properly. After I'll test this idea, I will get back with an answer.